# Multiple file upload with Vue and Axios

Tags: vue.js, file-upload, axios, vuejs3

I have some problems with uploading multiple files in Vue with Axios. The problem is that the FileList always returns a length of `0`, even if I select multiple files.

I have a button which opens a File Upload:

```
<v-icon @click="attachFile(user)">fas fa-paperclip</v-icon>
```

The function it calls:

```
attachFile(user) {
  document.getElementById(user.id).click();
},
```

The form input it refers to:

```
 <input
    :id="item.id"
    name="files[]"
    type="file"
    multiple
    hidden
    ref="files"
    @change="handleUpload()"
 />
```

And then in the `handleUpload()` I want to make an `axios` call to upload the files.

```
handleUpload() {
  this.files = this.$refs.files.files;
  console.log(this.files);
},
```

But `this.files` always returns a `FileList` with the length of `0`. I already set the `file` data in the function:

```
 data: () => ({
    files: "",
  })
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I can see your attempt seems to be fine basically. The error might be in your `$ref` itself. Instead of using a reference, you might solve your problem by simply accessing the passed in event in your function `handleUpload()`. You could achieve this by something like this.

```
handleUpload(e) {
  console.log(e.target.files);
}
```

This should probably work. A working example could be found [here](https://codesandbox.io/embed/friendly-ramanujan-lzdgo?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will help someone(not for the author, because I see that he avoided my mistake). I used an event 'click', but have to use a 'change' event. This thing has stoled a couple of hours from me.